# Retrive related data in a collection of array php

Tags: php, arrays, er-diagram

I'm designing a small application using pure PHP. I'm not going to use frameworks. This is my ER diagram.

[image: ER Diagram]

Users can add one or more user notes. And each note can be tagged by user. Users can search by note title, content and also note tags.

- When I'm going to show all notes in one page, I can get user details and note details in one query. But after that I need to retrieve tags using another query in a foreach loop. Is this good way to implement this?
- I have seen when I'm using some frameworks they retrieve data in a collection of array. How can I achieve this?
- I'm trying to give sorting feature using tags. I'm confusing that how do I sort notes using set of tags? Is there any way to achieve this also?

Comment: Actually I don't have time to practice them now.

Comment: you can try using group_concat() in mysql which will help you to get the associated tags for your note in one query

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't get all notes and note rags in a single query

Comment: Thanks. I will check this. I have added another question regarding sorting using tags.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes. As Manigandan Arjunan suggests I can retrieve them by grouping and concat them together and join with main query. Is this you think?

Comment: Don't use Frameworks !!! Rasmus Lerdorf itself explains why :)



https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anr7DQnMMs0